# ASP.net MVC themes changing help

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, themes, dynamic-css

I have a website developed using ASP.Net MVC. Now I want to based on the request(based on the country) I want to change the web site theme.

Ex: for USA - theme 1 
    for Canada - theme 2

If the request is not matching to any theme I want to display default (my current theme).

How can I achieve this dynamically.

Do I need to rewrite my css again or Is there a better way to this?

Please share your ideas

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Why not just have a common css file that holds non-country specific styles. Then when you detect the country, lets say you get a country code of UK for united kingdom, you then import a specific gb.css to apply over the top of your base CSS.

Comment: Actually my site layout wont change. If I can change images theme can be change. So Can I create image folders (like theme1, theme2) then Can I load those images ?? But is it possible to change css dynamically. Ex: I have change image path written in css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a global css file for common styles. Assuming you have some kind of helper method for accessing the current country, you can conditionally load the country specific stylesheet, or load a stylesheet based on a rule e.g. stylesheet with the same name as the country (following code is untested):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css">

// conditional

@if (SiteHelper.CurrentCountry == "USA") {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/usa.css">
}

// or assume a css file exists with the country name

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/@(SiteHelper.CurrentCountry).css">
```

I would generally recommend using a different layout page for each country/theme as it gives you much more control. Essentially you would move the above logic into _ViewStart.cshtml and set the Layout based on the current country.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best approach but this is what I am doing.  I have a folder structure similar to this:

```
   /Content
    layout.css
   /Content/Images
   /Content/Themes/ThemeUSA
                   layout.css
   /Content/Themes/ThemeUSA/Images
```

Then I use Helper Extensions to return the correct path for example for an image:

```
<img src="@Url.Image(Model.EnhImg)" alt="@Model.EnhImgAlt" />
```

where

```
public static string Image(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
{
    string sLocation = Content() + "images/" + fileName;
    return helper.Content(sLocation);
}

private static string Content()
{
    string sLocation = "~/content/";
    string sTheme = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Theme"];
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sTheme))
    {
        sLocation += "themes/" +sTheme + "/";
    }
    return sLocation;
}
```

Images in the theme folders have the same name as in the default folder. Same thing for stylesheets.